# geom_tile, scale_fill_manual where drop=FALSE does not work

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing a loop to draw several geom_tile graphs. The following codes are the inside part of the loop. For some columns (each column I use it to draw a geom_tile), the values may not fall into all interval I set up. In other words, there are some 0 counts for certain intervals. I used scale_fill_manual(values=rev(rbPal(break1)),labels=rev(cuts),drop=FALSE), where drop=FALSE should fix the problem, but it did not. Anyone could help? Really appreciate it! Thanks

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

color1<-c()
y1<-data[(1:(lifespan[i]*numbperday)),i]
max1<-max(y1)
n<-(lifespan[i]*numbperday)
dt <- data.table(t=0:(n-1))
dt[, y :=y1]
dt[,t_in_day := t%%numbperday]
dt[,day := (floor(t/numbperday)+1)]
dt2 <- copy(dt)
dt2[,day := day-1]

dt2[,t_in_day := t_in_day + numbperday]
dd <- rbind(dt, dt2)
dd <- dd[day>0]

dd[,day_str := sprintf("day\n%03d",day)]

dd[, day_str := as.ordered(day)]
dd[, day_str := ordered(day_str,levels=rev(levels(day_str)))]

rbPal <- colorRampPalette(c("white","blue"))
col1 <- rbPal(break1)[as.numeric(cut(dd[,y],breaks = breakvect))]

cuts<-levels(cut(dd[,y],breaks = breakvect))
cuts<-gsub(","," - ",cuts)
cuts<-gsub("\\(","[",cuts)
dd1<-cbind(dd,col1)


ggplot(dd1,aes(t_in_day,day_str, fill = col1)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_x_continuous(name="time (h)",breaks = 0:(numbperday*2)) +
  scale_y_discrete(name="starting day") + # scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "limegreen")
  scale_fill_manual(values=rev(rbPal(break1)),labels=rev(cuts),drop=FALSE)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example by pasting the output of `dput(dd1)` or a subset into your question.  I would also suggest removing code that is not pertinent to the problem, e.g. all the data manipulation. Please elaborate what is the purpose of the for loop?

Comment: hi, Djork, I have posted a complete program with comments on the following link. You could try on your own computer to see if you have any idea to fix it. Thank you very much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49780380/drop-false-does-not-work-for-geom-tile-when-i-have-some-0-counts-for-some-interv